# Regex to exempt prefix from matching

Tags: regex, logstash

My input is 
`/abc/pqr/xyz/efg/abc/` 

If I use the regex :
`([a-zA-Z]+)` 

I identify all the words in the path.
How can I exempt the prefix `/abc/pqr` from matching. 
My output needs to just match
`xyz, efg, abc`

What kind of an operator do I need? I want to use the regex in a gsub filter in logstash.

Comment: Which regex engine/flavour? The reason I ask is because `/abc/pqr(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[a-zA-Z]+` may be used, or `(?:\A/abc/pqr|\G(?!\A))/\K[a-zA-Z]+`, etc. But many regex engines don't allow those tokens.

Comment: I am using Logstash regex engine. Want to use the regex in a gsub filter.

Comment: @aethena - `(?<=/abc/pqr/)(.*)` is this ok ?

Comment: `'/abc/pqr/xyz/efg/abc/'.match(/(?<=\/abc\/pqr\/).*/)[0]` is what I have to escape the special characters